# Using breezeJs with angular

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, breeze

We are currently using breeze js with angular.

every time we call the server we have to add $scope.$apply

```
  $scope.SelectSection = function () {
        var id = $scope.SectionId;
        //SectionId
        dataContext.getCategoriesBySectionId(id).then(function(data) {
            $scope.Categories = data.results;
            $scope.$apply()
        });
    }
```

After I searched breeze website, I found out that we could use angular $http service as an "Ajax Implementation" for breeze and this should make us get rid of $scope.$apply() by adding the below code

```
angular.module('app').run(['$http', function ($http) {
    var ajax = breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('ajax', 'angular');
    ajax.setHttp($http); // use the $http instance that Angular injected into your app.
}]);
```

but unfortunately code still not working properly with out $scope.$apply()

does anyone have any advice??? thank you

Comment: Did you try using [`breeze.angular`](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-angular-service)?

Answer (score 0):

You might look at this ["Minimal Breeze/Angular" plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dYHSnDYqZq26uS31nhum?p=info) that uses the [*breeze.angular* module](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-angular-service) mentioned by @PSL. No use of `$scope.$apply` at all.